# Flow of logic when using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

*contrived example*

Say we need to construct a `Foo` and `Bar` for a `User` in some Node application. We are expected to implement the `constructFooForUser` function, which must invoke some `callback` function with either

- an `Error`
- a null error, the created `Foo`, and the created `Bar`

To do this, we must make use of some database functions which fetch/create our objects, returning a Promise.

```
var constructFooForUser = function(userId, data, callback) {

  db.users.find(userId)
    .then(function(user) {
      if (!user) { return callback(new Error('user not found')); }

      db.foos.create(user, data)
        .then(function(foo) {

          db.bars.create(user, foo, data)
            .then(function(bar) {

              callback(null, foo, bar);

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              callback(err);
            });

        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          callback(err);
        });

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      callback(err);
    });

};
```

**Is this the correct way to structure this type of promise based code?**

I've seen examples of Promise code which looks like

```
doSomething()
  .then(doSomethingElse)
  .then(doYetAnotherThing)
  .then(doLastThing)
  .catch(handleError);
```

but I don't think this works in this scenario, as I need user, foo, and bar at the same time, and scope isn't shared between the chained functions.

I ask because the code looks repetitive, so I am wondering if something is unusual.

**EDIT: Forgot to include `foo` in the creation of `bar`**

Answer (score 1):

How about storing `foo` in some variable until we need it?

```
var constructFooForUser = function(userId, data, callback) {

  var gFoo;

  db.users.find(userId)
    .then(function(user) {
      if (!user) { return callback(new Error('user not found')); }

      return db.foos.create(user, data)
    })
    .then(function(foo) {
      gFoo = foo;

      return db.bars.create(user, data)
    })
    .then(function(bar) {
      callback(null, gFoo, bar);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      callback(err);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically (and yes I consider this a hacky workaround) accumulate the results in an array as I go.

```
firstThing()
  .then(first => Promise.all([first, secondThing]))
  .then(([first, second]) => Promise.all([first, second, thirdThing()]))
  .catch(e => handleErr(e));
```

This accumulation pattern works, and with ES 2015 destructuring its not *too* clunky.

Answer (score 0):

foo and bar don't seem to depend on each other, so we could make this part paralell:

```
var constructFooForUser = function(userId, data, callback) {
    db.users.find(userId).then(function(user) {
        //because rejecting a promise means nothing else than throwing an Error
        if(!user) throw new Error('user not found');

        //resolves as soon as both requests have been resolved. 
        //rejects if _any_ of the requests is rejecting
        return Promise.all([
            db.foos.create(user, data),
            db.foos.create(user, data)
        ]);
    }).then(
        ([foo, bar]) => callback(null, foo, bar), //utilizing array destructuring
        (err) => callback(err)
    );
}
```

I'm using `.then(a, b)` instead of `.then(a).catch(b)`, because the latter would also catch Errors that are thrown in your callback-function (and we don't want that); that's your responsibility to deal with them. It would hide bugs in your code, by error-messages simply not showing up in the console.

Even your attempt with the nested promises could be streamlined by returning the promises and concatenating at least the error-part

```
var constructFooForUser = function(userId, data, callback) {
  db.users.find(userId)
    .then(function(user) {
      if (!user) throw new Error('user not found');

      return db.foos.create(user, data)
        .then( foo => db.bars.create(user, data).then( bar => callback(null, foo, bar) ) );
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      callback(err);
    });
};
```